# Procedurally generated mesh has all normals inverted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, mesh

Hellos guys,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to read a json file to create a scene at runtime. Serialization/deserialization works fine.

The main problem is, I want to be able to create meshes from 8 points/vertices, I sort of achieve this, but every single normal is inverted, and I don't understand why.

This is my json input for one :

```
"name": "whatever",
        "points": [
            {
                "x": -1,
                "y": -0.05,
                "z": 1
            },
            {
                "x": -1,
                "y": 0.05,
                "z": 1
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 0.05,
                "z": 1
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": -0.05,
                "z": 1
            },
            {
                "x": -1,
                "y": -0.05,
                "z": -1
            },
            {
                "x": -1,
                "y": 0.05,
                "z": -1
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 0.05,
                "z": -1
            },
            {
                "x": 1,
                "y": -0.05,
                "z": -1
            }
        ]
```

and this is my mesh generation code in c# :

```
public void GenerateMesh(SerializedMesh data)
{
    Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[data.points.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.points.Count; i++)
    {
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(data.points[i].x, data.points[i].y, data.points[i].z);
    }

    int[] triangles = {
        // Front face
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,

        // Back face
        7, 6, 5,
        5, 4, 7,

        // Left face
        4, 5, 1,
        1, 0, 4,

        // Right face
        3, 2, 6,
        6, 7, 3,

        // Top face
        1, 5, 6,
        6, 2, 1,

        // Bottom face
        4, 0, 3,
        3, 7, 4
    };

    // TODO : check what all this does
    Mesh.Clear();
    Mesh.vertices = vertices;
    Mesh.triangles = triangles;
    //Mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    Mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    //Mesh.RecalculateTangents();
    //Mesh.Optimize();
}
```

I represented my vertices in this order :

[image: cube]

How come everything is inverted ?

Comment: The JSON does not agree with the numbering in your image. E.g. vertex 0 has x-coordinate -1, but the picture clearly shows a positive x-coordinate. Are you transforming the mesh (e.g. mirroring)?

Comment: Mmmh, in unity, X goes positive on the right so it should be fine ?

Answer (score 2):

- Because you tried counter-clockwise winding you should change vertex list or index list as clockwise winding. for your case, -1 for z-axis is front face and 1 is back face so you should set index list as opposite. I just converted first 2 triangles.

```
int[] triangles = {
        // Back face
        0, 3, 2,
        0, 2, 1,

        ...
        ...
    };
```

Comment: 0, 1, 2 for front face is clock wise, not counter clock wise ?

Comment: Unity z-axis increasing is back and decreasing is front so as I mentioned answer,

Comment: Mostly, problem is wrong winding drawing, so try it opposite will see.

Comment: In this example that you given here, you can see that cube on 'Scene' tab but you will not see cube in 'Game'  tab because It will be removed by backface remover.

Comment: I just inverted the Z on the json, everything is fine now

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was just silly. My "reference" cube had a Y rotation of 180, I thought it would not do any difference but it does.

The problem was that in the json, the Z positions were inverted (1 -> -1 and vice versa)

Everything works fine now, thanks !